# Button com cookie e location

Tags: cookies, button, onclick

No início da minha página inclui o cookie:

`<?php setcookie("agenda","2016");?>`

No final da página, sem usar formulário, tenho o seguinte button:

`<button class="button button1" onclick="location.href='escolha_sala.php?inst=Manaus';">Manaus</button>`

Como eu faço para ir pra página seguinte `escolha_sala.php` mas enviar os dados `inst=Manaus` pro cookie usando esse button e sem usar formulário?

Quero escolher um dos botões, clicar nele, salvar os dados correspondentes no cookie e ir automático p/ página seguinte.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de algum tempo e imaginação encontrei isso daqui:
Vou testando....

`<?php
  setcookie("agenda","2016");
  function button() {
    setcookie("inst","Manaus");
  }
  if (isset($_GET['hello'])) {
    button();
  }
?>`